# Preventing redirects for file serving in apache

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration, httpd, 301-redirect, file-server

I am working with a specific proprietary (and no longer properly supporter) http client, and it has an issue of giving up on trying to download files if an http server throws a 301. I am using mod_speling with `CheckSpelling On` and `CheckCaseOnly On`, and what I am describing happens when a request is made with the path, for example, being `/documentroot/Media/audio.mp3`, while the actual path is `/documentroot/media/audio.mp3` (also same goes for request of `/documentroot/Media/Audio.mp3`/`/documentroot/media/Audio.mp3` and actual path being `/documentroot/media/audio.mp3`), so a redirect is made to that path. Is there a way to avoid a redirect and serve files directly, even if there is a mismatch in case somewhere in requested path?

Comment: why not using lower cased letters for all your files and requests?

Comment: @djdomi, "I am working with a specific proprietary (and no longer properly supporter) http client"(C). I have no control over it.